# Instagram Login Error - sorry there was a problem with your request instagram

Tags: applications, instagram

Instagram Login Error -

[image: sorry there was a problem with your request instagram]

What is the reason for receiving this error message in the Instagram?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem few weeks ago and i figured two ways to get over it.

1. This option is for people who have a different phone in handy. You just have to login to your instagram using a different phone(and the irony is that it allows you to login there). Then you link your instagram with facebook. Logout from instagram and then log back in to instagram using your original phone with facebook.

Now, if you don't have another phone with you or you don't have a facebook account, you can try option 2.

2. This option requires you to download an app called [parallel space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&hl=en_IN). this app basically clones all the apps present on your device. And then using this app you can successfully login to your instagram.